# Uniform distribution Measure

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, uniform-distribution, product-space

Assume $\mu$ is the $U([0,1]^2)$ defined by

$$\mu([0,x]\times[0,y]=xy, \ (x,y) \in [0,1]^2$$

Show that $\mu$ assigns probability of $0$ to $\partial([0,1]^2)$

I tried to write each segment of the four segments of $\partial([0,1]^2)$ as a Cartesian product of two sets $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ to be able to use the definition?

Comment: Should I use the complement?

Comment: can I apply $ \mu $ on a clopen interval, i.e. $[0,1)$

Answer (score 2):

Let $U=\{(x,1)\,|\,x\in [0,1]\}$, $R=\{(1,y)\,|\,y\in [0,1]\}$, $L=\{(0,y)\,|\,y\in [0,1]\}$, and $D=\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in [0,1]\}$. It is clear that $\partial ([0,1]^2)=L\cup R\cup U\cup D$.

Notice that for all $x,y\in [0,1)$ we have
$$U\cup R\subseteq [0,1]^2\backslash [0,x]\times [0,y],$$
so 
$$\mu(U\cup R)\le \mu([0,1]^2)-\mu ([0,x]\times [0,y])=1-xy$$
for all $x,y\in [0,1)$, showing that $\mu(U\cup R)=0$. Since the Lebesgue measure is shift-invariant, we see that $\mu(U\cup R)=\mu(D\cup L)$. Thus, 
$$0\le \mu(\partial ([0,1]^2)=\mu(U\cup R\cup L\cup D)\le \mu(U\cup R)+ \mu(L\cup D)=0$$

Comment: I kind of arrived to a result similar where I derived $1-xy$. I guess  $1-xy$ would equal $0$ because $x, y \in [0,1]$